# Como especifico que me muestre la descripcion de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo Una consulta para mostrar y si me lo muestra pero el problema esta en que 2 de mis campos de diferentes tablas se llaman igual y en las dos me arroja el mismo dato de contenido, como puedo hacer para que me muestre los dos distintos campos sin modificar la estructura de mi base de datos.

Este es mi codigo y en las tablas de Producto y de contenido es donde tengo los campos Descripcion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mostrar foto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="http://localhost/El grano/">Home</a></th>
                <th><a href="form_productos.php">Nuevo Registro</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>CLAVE</td>
                <td>NOMBRE</td>
                <td>PRECIO</td>
                <td>FOTO</td>
                <td>MARCA</td>
                <td>EXISTENCIAS</td>
                <td>TIPO DE CONTENIDO</td>
                <td>CLASIFICACION</td>
                <td>PROVEEDOR</td>
                <td>MODIFICAR</td>
                <td>ELIMINAR</td>
            </tr>               
            <?php
                require('conectar.php');
                $consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT Id_producto, Productos.Descripcion, Precio, Productos.Foto, Marca, Existencias, contenido.Descripcion, clasificacion.Tipo, Usuarios.NOMBRE FROM Productos JOIN contenido JOIN clasificacion JOIN Usuarios WHERE Productos.Id_contenido = contenido.Id_contenido AND Productos.Id_clasificacion = clasificacion.Id_clasificacion AND Productos.Id_usuario = Usuarios.Id_usuario");
                $consulta->execute();
                $resultado = $consulta->fetchALL();
                foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
            ?>
            <tr>    
                <td><?php echo $fila["Id_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Descripcion"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Precio"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo '<img src="'.$fila["Foto"].'" width="100px" height="100px">'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Marca"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Existencias"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Descripcion"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Tipo"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["NOMBRE"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="modificar_productos.php?id_producto=<?php echo $fila['Id_producto']; ?>">EDITAR</a></td>
                <td><a href="eliminar_productos.php? id_producto=<?php echo $fila['Id_producto']; ?>">ELIMINAR</a> </td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            } 
            ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu consulta, ponle un sobrenombre a tus descripciones:

```
<?php
                require('conectar.php');
                $consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT Id_producto, Productos.Descripcion as DescripcionProducto, Precio, Productos.Foto, Marca, Existencias, contenido.Descripcion as DescripcionContenido, clasificacion.Tipo, Usuarios.NOMBRE FROM Productos JOIN contenido JOIN clasificacion JOIN Usuarios WHERE Productos.Id_contenido = contenido.Id_contenido AND Productos.Id_clasificacion = clasificacion.Id_clasificacion AND Productos.Id_usuario = Usuarios.Id_usuario");
                $consulta->execute();
                $resultado = $consulta->fetchALL();
                foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
            ?>
```

ahora, las columnas se llamarán `DescripcionProducto` y `DescripcionContenido`. deberás cambiar tus echos de la parte inferior del código:

```
<tr>    
                <td><?php echo $fila["Id_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["DescripcionProducto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Precio"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo '<img src="'.$fila["Foto"].'" width="100px" height="100px">'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Marca"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Existencias"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["DescripcionContenido"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["Tipo"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila["NOMBRE"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="modificar_productos.php?id_producto=<?php echo $fila['Id_producto']; ?>">EDITAR</a></td>
                <td><a href="eliminar_productos.php? id_producto=<?php echo $fila['Id_producto']; ?>">ELIMINAR</a> </td>
            </tr>
```

Espero te sirva, ¡saludos!